# How can I insert a record into a custom table from my custom form in my custom admin page?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm struggling with this one and all of the relevant links to the codex, articles and forum posts (stack or otherwise) that I've searched haven't helped.

I can best describe my problem as attempting to replicate the native "Add New User" Wordpress functionality. I.e. render a form from an admin page, insert a new record from this form (the equivalent of adding a new user) and update the table.

So far I have:

[image: Add Episodes Form]

The plugin code so far looks like:

```
<?php
    /*

    Plugin Name: Episodes

    Description: The episodes plugin

    Author: Nick Courage

    Version: 1.0

    */

    function activate_episodes(){

        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'episodes';

        if($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE' . $table_name) != $table_name){

            $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table_name . '(

                episode_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

                episode_title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

                episode_desc VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

                air_date DATE NOT NULL,

                img_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

                PRIMARY KEY (episode_id)

                )';

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    dbDelta($sql);

    add_option('episode_database_version', '1.0');

    }
    }

    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'activate_episodes');

    function episodes_add_page(){

        ?>
        <h1>Add Episodes</h1>
        <form method="$_POST" action="">
            <label for="episode_title">Episode Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="episode_title" id="episode_title" />
            <label for="episode_desc">Episode Description:</label>
            <input type="text" name="episode_desc" id="episode_desc" />
            <label for="air_date">Air date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="air_date" id="air_date" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>


        <?php

    }

    function episodes_plugin_menu(){

        add_menu_page('Episodes Page', 'Episodes', 'manage_options','episodes-plugin','episodes_add_page');

    }

    add_action('admin_menu','episodes_plugin_menu');




    function add_episode(){

        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'episodes';

        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('episode_title'=>$_POST['episode_title'],

            'episode_desc'=>$POST['episode_desc'],

            'air_date'=>$_POST['air_date'],

            'img_url'=>$_POST['img_url']

            )

        );

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: not an answer to your question, but why use a custom table rather than a custom post type and post meta?

Comment: Your right...That's not an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [admin-post action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) to intercept POST requests and process forms. The [`admin_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) function can be used to output the correct URL, and use [`wp_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to redirect back to your plugin page after processing.

And do yourself and your users a favor- don't reinvent wheels and add tables when the native tables and API can be used.

Comment: Ok I'll investigate. My reason for custom tables was so I could keep up with the relationships between seasons, links etc. In any case, Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    /*

    Plugin Name: Episodes

    Description: The episodes plugin

    Author: Nick Courage

    Version: 1.0

    */

function activate_episodes()
{

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'episodes';

    if ($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE' . $table_name) != $table_name) {

        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table_name . '(

                episode_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

                episode_title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

                episode_desc VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

                air_date DATE NOT NULL,

                img_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

                PRIMARY KEY (episode_id)

                )';

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

        dbDelta($sql);

        add_option('episode_database_version', '1.0');
    }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate_episodes');

function episodes_add_page()
{
    global $wpdb;
    if (
        !empty($_POST)
        && $_POST['episode_title'] != ''
        && $_POST['episode_desc'] != ''
        && $_POST['air_date'] != ''
    ) {

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'episodes';
        $episode_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['episode_title']);
        $episode_desc = sanitize_text_field($_POST['episode_desc']);
        $air_date = sanitize_text_field($_POST['air_date']);

        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'episode_title' => $episode_title,
                'episode_desc' => $episode_desc,
                'air_date' => $air_date
            )
        );
    }
    ?>

    <h1>Add Episodes</h1>
    <form method="post" action="?page=episodes-plugin">
        <label for="episode_title">Episode Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="episode_title" id="episode_title" />
        <label for="episode_desc">Episode Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="episode_desc" id="episode_desc" />
        <label for="air_date">Air date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="air_date" id="air_date" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

<?php
}



function episodes_plugin_menu()
{


    add_menu_page(
        "Paginas episodios",
        "Episodios",
        "manage_options",
        "episodes-plugin",
        "episodes_add_page",
        "dashicons-video-alt3",
        75
    );
}



add_action('admin_menu', 'episodes_plugin_menu');
```